# Dependency Injection Implementations aren't the same

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm a little bit noob with this and I would like to ask the following:

I'm trying to Inject a MyDbContext class vía DI and tried 2 things:

First, in `Program.cs` I've got

`builder.Services.AddScoped<MyDbContext>(p => new MyDbContext(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApiDotnetDb")));`

In the `MyDbContext` class I've got:

```
    private readonly String _connString;

    public MyDbContext(String connString)
    {
        this._connString = connString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder opt)
    {
        opt.UseMySQL(this._connString);
    }
```

And everything compile and its ok but if I try:

In `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(opt => opt.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApiDotnetDb")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped,
  ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

And then in `MyDbContextClass` like this:

```
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        
    }
```

I get

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: webapi.MyDbContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: webapi.MyDbContext': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext]' while attempting to activate 'webapi.MyDbContext'.)'
```

What could it be?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the generic argument for `DbContextOptions<T>` to use your derived `DbContext` class:

```
public MyDbContext( DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options ) 
    : base( options ) 
{
}
```

Comment: You were right, I feel shame right now hahaha. Thanks!